# radioGroupButton in bottomsheet fragment not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i am unable to gettext() from selected radio button in radioGroup. in my case i am getting value from bottomsheet and trying to get radio button text from fragment but
only one button is displaying the text. would you please check and let me know where i am wrong. thanks very much.

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

EditText editText;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButtonCash,radioButtonCard;
Button btn;
int i=0;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view= inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false );

    editText=(EditText)view.findViewById ( R.id.addAmount );

    btn=(Button)view.findViewById ( R.id.saveBtn );
    radioGroup=(RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioGrp);

    int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId ();
    radioButtonCash=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( selectedId );
    radioButtonCard=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( selectedId );



    btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            i = Integer.parseInt (editText.getText ().toString () );
            new bgthread ().start ();


            if (selectedId==-1)
            {
                Toast.makeText ( getContext (), "nothing to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
            }
            else if (selectedId==R.id.radioButtonCash)
            {
                Toast.makeText ( getContext (), "text is"+radioButtonCash.getText (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
            }
            else if (selectedId==R.id.radioButtonCard)
            {
                Toast.makeText ( getContext (), "text is"+radioButtonCard.getText (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
            }

        }
    } );

    return view;


}
```

}

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addAmount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:hint="@string/enter_amount"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/freenowImg"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/freenowImg"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/freenowImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/freenow"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/addAmount"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addAmount"
    android:contentDescription="TODO">

</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/boltImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bolt"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/addAmount"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/freenowImg"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addAmount" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/uberImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:src="@drawable/uber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/freenowImg"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/freenowImg"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/freenowImg" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#009688"
    android:text="Save"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uberImg"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.951" />


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveBtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uberImg">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/cash"
       />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/card" />
</RadioGroup>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Try getText().toString();

Comment: i get null execption

Answer (score 1):

this block of your code just run once and not checked **selectedId** value after  **oncheckedChange** call:

```
    int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId ();
```

try this :

```
String strRbTxt="nothing to show";
radioGroup.setOncheckedChangedListener(new RadioGroup.onChecked....
{
  switch(checkedId){
   case R.id.radioButtonCash:
    strRbTxt=radioButtonCash.getText ();
break;

case R.id.radioButtonCard:
    strRbtxt=radioButtonCard.getText ();
break;
}
 
}

btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
       .....   
 Toast.makeText ( getContext (), "text is "+strRbtxt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        }
    } );
```

**udpdate 1 :**
change your findviewbyId from :

```
 int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId ();
    radioButtonCash=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( selectedId );
    radioButtonCard=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( selectedId );
```

to and again try my code :

```
radioButtonCash=(RadioButton)view.findViewById (R.id.radioButtonCash);     
radioButtonCard=(RadioButton)view.findViewById (R.id.radioButtonCard);
```

Comment: thanks for your help but still is not working i am getting null error

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: dude change this : `int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId ();
    radioButtonCash=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( selectedId );
    radioButtonCard=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( selectedId );` to     `radioButtonCash=(RadioButton)view.findViewById (R.id.radioButtonCash);
    radioButtonCard=(RadioButton)view.findViewById (R.id.radioButtonCard);` and try my code again

Comment: you get null pointer exeption beacuse this block of your code just run once and not checked selectedId value after oncheckedChange  `int selectedId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId ();`

Comment: i have done but its giving showing me only card even if i click on cash i only getting card Text. if i change in xml either cash or card button in to this option "android:checked="true"" wil only show me that text. for example if i mark cash radio button checked true will show me only cash getText. hope you understand. thanks

Answer (score 1):

so finally i have find the solution specifically according to the problem i faced. in my case within the fragment the radio group was not working properly i used if else statement but i was getting id only for one radio button at a time.

now i am using switch statement within "radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener" and its working absolutely according.

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

EditText editText;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButtonCash,radioButtonCard;
Button btn;
int i=0;
CharSequence strRbTxt="";





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view= inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false );

    btn=(Button)view.findViewById ( R.id.saveBtn );
    radioGroup=(RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioGrp);


    editText=(EditText)view.findViewById ( R.id.addAmount );
    radioButtonCash=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( R.id.radioButtonCash );
    radioButtonCard=(RadioButton)view.findViewById ( R.id.radioButtonCard );

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener ( new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener () {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

            switch (i)


            {
                case R.id.radioButtonCash:
                    strRbTxt=radioButtonCash.getText ().toString ();
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButtonCard:
                    strRbTxt=radioButtonCard.getText ().toString ();
                    break;
            }

        }
    } );


    btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            i = Integer.parseInt (editText.getText ().toString () );
            new bgthread ().start ();
            Toast.makeText ( getContext (), "text is"+strRbTxt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();

        }
    } );

    return view;


}
```